# Get the scroll position from an Angular Material Tab content

Tags: angular-material, scrollbar, angular-cdk

I use an Angular Material Tab component with custom components as content for the tabs.
The tabs list come from an API.

I need to get the scroll index of the `mat-tab-body-content` as the element with this class has the `scrollTop` value I need.

I could get the `scrollTop` value by using the following JS expression:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('mat-tab-body-content')[index];
```

Where `index` is the selected Tab and `mat-tab-body-content` has the scroll position within it.
 The problem is that I cannot find an event that gets triggered *before* changing Tab, plus this approach is incomplete, since all changes done to the current Tab and when changing Route are not considered.

Here my template for the root container component:

```
<section class="page">
    <ng-container *ngIf="adressenTabsList$ | async as tabsContainer">
        <form [formGroup]="adressenForm" *ngIf="tabsContainer.tabsList.length > 0 && !isLoading; else noResults">

            <mat-tab-group animationDuration="0ms" selectedTabChange)="onTabSelected($event)">
                
              <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabsContainer.tabsList; trackBy: trackById; index as idx"
                    [label]="tab.label">
                    <span [ngSwitch]="tab.tabLabelKey">

                        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="tabsType.kunde">
                            <kunde-tab [kundeForm]="kundeForm"></kunde-tab>
                            </ng-container>
                        </ng-container>

                        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="tabsType.personen">
                           ...
                        </ng-container>
                     </span>
                  </mat-tab>
            </mat-tab-group>
        
  </section>
```

In the component I simply get the tab object from the backend:

```
  this.adressenTabsList$ = this.adressenService.getTabs()
      .pipe(
        map((list: TabList) => list)
      );
```

I would like to be able, for each Tab content, to get the `scrollTop` value of the element with class `mat-tab-body-content` (as displayed in the picture below).

[image]

I tried to interact with the scrollable tab content with the following code, but I noticed that there are no registered scrollable elements (even though the mat tab content has the `cdkscrollable` directive applied (see picture above), therefore the following code never gets triggered:

```
      this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled()
        .pipe(
        )
        .subscribe((cdk: CdkScrollable) => {
          this.zone.run(() => {
            const scrollPosition = cdk.getElementRef().nativeElement.scrollTop;
            console.log(scrollPosition);
          });
        });
```

Comment: did you eventually find the solution? would be great to share... I am having the same issue

Comment: Have a look at my answer, where I describe how I could solve the issue above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my problem using the private event handler `_handleClick`  from the `_MatTabGroupBase` abstract class to intercept a Tab click and then apply our logic accordingly.

I described the process in a [Dev.to article](https://dev.to/paco_ita/add-logic-to-run-before-current-material-tab-changes-kif) if you are interested.

Below the involved code:

**Template**

```
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start">
  <mat-tab label="First">Content first tab</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second">Content second tab</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third">Content third tab</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**Component class**

```
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Component,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import { MatTabChangeEvent, MatTabGroup } from '@angular/material/tabs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component,
  templateUrl: './app-component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

// Get a reference of the MatTabGroup form the template
@ViewChild(MatTabGroup)
tabs?: MatTabGroup;

private currentTabIndex = 0;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.registerTabClick();
}

registerTabClick(): void {
  // Get the handler reference
  const handleTabClick = this.tabs._handleClick;

  this.tabs._handleClick = (tab, header, index) => {  
    // Get tab content reference for the current Tab -> currentTabIndex
    // since index here is already the "new" tab index
    const tabContent = this.getTabContentElement(this.currentTabIndex);

    const scrollPosition = Math.round(tabContent.scrollTop) || 0;

    this.store.dispatch(
       setTabScrollPosition({
         scrollPosition: scrollPosition,
         // ... other props
       })
    );

   // If you want to prevent the user to navigate to the new tab,
   // you can avoid invoking the 'apply' method below 
   handleTabClick.apply(this.tabs, [tab, header, index]);

   // We update the currentIndex, as we need it again when
   // another tab is clicked
   this.currentTabIndex = index;
  };
}

 // Returns the <mat-tab-body-content> with the tab content scroll 
 position given the target tab index
 private getTabContentElement(tabIndex: number) {
   return document.getElementsByClassName('mat-tab-body-content')[tabIndex];
 }
}
```